# creating folder in php by running wshell command

Tags: php, shell

i want to run a php file through command prompt and i have used mkdir in the php code to make the directory.
but when i execute the code from cmd/wshell command, the folder is never created.

```
//i use this when i run the test.php file from cmd.
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php-win.exe -f c:\wamp\www\test\test.php
```

test.php contains:

```
<?php
    mkdir("C://wamp/www/test/testrr",0777,true);
    file_put_contents("C://wamp/www/test/del.txt","lol");
?>
```

the del.txt file is created but the "testrr" folder is never created.
I've run the command as administrator.

Comment: the php file creates the folder when i run it on the browser

Comment: Any notices ? Enable error reports ... `error_reporting = E_ALL` in `php.ini`

Comment: Do you have specific authentication to create a folder with shell user run by php

Comment: error reports are enabled. But i dont know where the reports are being generated.

Answer (score 0):

Give %system32%\cmd.exe read/execute permissions to IUSR account.
or you can use SysInternals Pseexec:

```
<?php
exec("md 'data'");
?>
```

or use Windows scripting shell COM object:

```
<?php
function _exec($cmd)
{
   $WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
   $oExec = $WshShell->Run($cmd, 0,false);
   echo $cmd;
   return $oExec == 0 ? true : false;
}_exec("whatever");
?>
```